# mysqli_fetch_assoc(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, string given

Tags: php, mysql

I updating a old volunteer website from Joomla 2.5 to Joomla 4 (PHP 5.4 to PHP 8.1) and mysql to mysqli. A few parts of the website were created by hand with php. So far by searching I have been able to get the custom php pages to work with the exception of this.

I am pulling names from a table and one of the columns has last and first names with a comma. This seems to be an issue now when it was not before. For example:

```
First Name: John
Last Name: Doe
The column would contain: Doe, John
```

When I run the following:

```
$dbcon = mysqli_connect("localhost","myuser","mypass","mydb");
$volunteer =& JFactory::getUser()->id;
$volunteername = mysqli_query($dbcon,"SELECT lastfirstnames FROM lastfirstnames WHERE id='$volunteer'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($volunteername)) { $volunteername = $row['lastfirstnames']; }
```

I get the following error:
**mysqli_fetch_assoc(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, string given**

I have been trying to figure this out for about 3 hours now and I am at the end of my rope. I am by no means a programmer, I am simply able to piece things together by searching.

Thank You very much for any assistance provided!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.